# Prevent Outlook 2016 Windows from resizing table cells

Tags: outlook, html-email, outlook-2016

We're banging our heads on an issue where we have a nicely formatted HTML newsletter that, once it's sent to someone on Windows using Outlook 2016, completely blows up.

The main issue is that the email is meant to be fixed-width but Outlook 2016 renders it full width.

After much frustration we realized the following:

- Creating the HTML email in Mac 16 Outlook is fine
- Sending it from Mac 16 Outlook is fine
- Reading it in Mac 16 Outlook is fine
- Reading it in Windows Outlook 2016 breaks it
- Forwarding said email from windows to Mac also shows the issue on the Mac.

I *think* I found out what is causing the issue, but not why it's happening. When I view the source of the forwarded email, I see that the widths of some of my tables have been forced to a much larger setting.

So, whereas I had:

```
<td width="793"...
```

The source in the broken email now shows:

```
<td width="1118" style="width: 594.75pt...
```

I'm stumped. Is Windows Outlook resizing TD indicative of anything in particular I need to do in my HTML to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

We found the answer. The issue was that inside this table, we had a nested table, and inside that table, we had an image and that image was set to `width="100%"`. Even though this was inside a table that also had a width set, it appears that Microsoft Outlook interprets that 100% to be 100% of...the viewport, maybe? Not entirely sure, but clearly it doesn't limit itself to its parent container's width.

The fix in our case was to hard-code a width for the image rather than tell it to be 100%.